# Find the number of days between today and specific date?

Tags: mysql

I want to find the number of days between today and selected date. 
I used one query

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), TILLDATE) FROM interestpr_table WHERE GLID="150";
```

But it returns NULL as result. How to fix?

Comment: you forgot `from table_name`

Comment: because you doesn't specify the table name from where you want to extract data

Comment: Are GLID and TILLDATE in a table?  I don't see a FROM statement in your query...

Comment: Make sure, your TILLDATE is in format : `YYYYMMDD`

Comment: @denny  Updated the qn

Comment: @LolCoder아카쉬  
My TILLDATE is 2017-03-19

Comment: you should have tilldate = 20170319

Comment: @LolCoder아카쉬 Its working when replace the date with20170319

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your TILLDATE is in format `YYYY-MM-DD`,  you need to change it in `YYYYMMDD` format so that `DATEDIFF` would accept it as valid format.

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/309c91/2)

For converting your date to format which `DATEDIFF` accept, you can use `DATE_FORMAT` like this :

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(curdate(),DATE_FORMAT(TILLDATE,'%Y%m%d')) // '%Y%m%d'converts it into YYYYMMDD format
```

[SQLFIDDLE for conversion](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e3468/8)

Comment: My TILLDATE in in the database ,So How can i convert to the same format as you mentioned(YYYY-MM-DD to YYYYMMDD )